Проблема с библиотекой PDFLib, при генерации PDF файла
Есть скрипт для генерации PDF:
'''
    const { PDFDocument } = PDFLib;        

    // PDF Generate  *************************************************************************************************
    async function flattenForm() {

        // Загружаем PDF с формой
        const formUrl = customData.pdfPath;
        const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer());
        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);

        // Получаем форму с полями
        const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
        console.log('form = ',form);
        // Задаем значения для полей

        const InvoiceNumber = form.getTextField('Invoice Number')
        const Name = form.getTextField('Name')
        const ID = form.getTextField('ID')  
        
        InvoiceNumber.setText('Mario')
        Name.setText('24 years')
        ID.setText(`5' 1"`)
        // Другие поля...
    
//------------------------------------------------------

      // Serialize the PDFDocument to bytes (a Uint8Array)
      const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save()

            // Trigger the browser to download the PDF document
      download(pdfBytes, "generated-document.pdf", "application/pdf");

    }'''

В консоль выдает ошибку: "Uncaught (in promise) ", в строке "download(pdfBytes, "generated-document.pdf", "application/pdf");"
Подскажите в чем проблема может быть? Кто сталкивался?
Заранее благодарен всем!!!
